# Database structure / defined and undefined field values

Tags: mysql, database, structure

I am using MySQL and have an `articles` table which has 2 columns: `currency` and `price`, but an article can also have a `negotiated price`, so I can't determine `currency` and `price` values.

What should I do to be able to have defined and negotiated prices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the negotiated price is specific to a user/business... , then this is probably a one to many relationship,  you will need a tuple table to hold the price and link the article to the other object.

e.g:
(I'll assume the price is negotiated with a user)

```
CREATE TABLE user_article_price (          
    articleid INT,          
    userid    INT,        
    price     DECIMAL(13,2)
)
```

You then simply need to `LEFT JOIN` to this table and use `NVL(user_article_price.price, article.price)`
to get the overridden value.

Note: It is probably a good idea to make a compound primary key using the 2 id columns to stop duplicate values.

Comment: yes, it's `one to many` user can have many articles, but problem is how to determine that article can have exact and negotiated price...

I was offered to define negotiated price with `currency` and `price` columns in this way: `currency = nil`, `price = -1`

Comment: I have no idea what logic you use to select the override price? in my example I select the override if it exists in preference to the actual price using NVL. Of course you could select both prices and do what you want with the values.